# How do I properly encode a mailto link?

Tags: asp.net, html, xss, urlencode, mailto

I am generating some HTML and I want to generate an XSS- and database-content-safe `mailto` link.  What is the proper encoding to use here?  How's this?

```
myLiteral.Text = string.Format(
  "mailto:{0}?Content-Type=text/html&amp;Subject={1}&amp;body={2}", 
  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(email_address),
  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(subject),
  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(body_message));
```

Should I use `UrlEncode` here?  `HtmlEncode`?  Do what I did, then `HtmlEncode` the entirety?  I'm writing HTML of a URL, so I'm a little unclear...

@Quentin, is this what you're describing?  (Changed `&amp;`s to `&` since I'm about to `HtmlEncode`...)

```
myLiteral.Text = 
  HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(
    string.Format(
      "mailto:{0}?Content-Type=text/html&Subject={1}&body={2}", 
      email_address, subject, body_message)));
```

Comment: Your first version is almost correct, except you should unencode the `&amp;`s. You are assigning it to the Text property. It should take care of the HTML encoding internally. The only thing you need to worry about is it being a valid URI.

Comment: @liho1eye: I think that's only true for an ASP Literal if myLiteral.Mode == Encode, which is not the default.  But the second version should have the effect you were going for, yes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are putting some content in a URL, then representing that URL in HTML. So URLEncode it then HTMLEncode what you get from URLEncode.

Comment: I tried.. is the 2nd version of the code in my question what you had in mind?

Comment: I would go with the first one. Or a mix of the two. Htmlattributeencoding the whole value, and url encoding the values inserted into the url

Comment: @Yuck — It is really an answer. The second sentence describes exactly what needs to be done.

Comment: @ScottStafford — Just seen the comment (2.5 years later), "yes".