# Open default mail client on button click with filled html in body

Tags: c#-4.0

[image]

I want to open mail window with pre filled html in body and subject.

Note: user need to enter to: email only, body should be filled by me from code side and body should fill with html.

1. Above image is screen shot which I need.
2. I  need image as shown as above in html body on clicking button.

Comment: may be duplicate question. See the below link for reference


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414320/to-open-outlook-new-email-window-with-content-already-filled

Comment: Dear @AMS Question is almost same, but my requirement is somewhat different read my question carefully..

Comment: @AMs need to fill html content in body not the string

Answer (score 0):

you can embed the html tag in string like this

```
string textBody="Hi
<strong>"+UserName+"</strong>
<br />"+Addrss +"  is you addrsss you can find current addrss 
<table>
<tr><td>Any other contant</td></tr>
</table>";
```

Is that what you want or something else. can you show what output you want so I can help

Comment: You can design using HTML tags as per your requirement.

Comment: I need output like above window

Comment: string text body =
"<html><body><table backgroud="red" color="white" width="200px" height="500px">
<tr>
<td style="font-family:Vardana; font-size:30;">
CLEAR THE RACK
<td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-size:20px;">
OCT 2 - OCT 5
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-size:20px;">
Take an <b>extra 25% OFF </b> All Red tag Clearance *
</td>
</tr>
</table></body></html>";

It will look like something like that.
May be syntactically wrong at some time as i have edited in plain notepad

Comment: haha :)  that is an image.  for your information .  i need to add hyperlinks also

Comment: mailto:?body=<html><body><table backgroud="red" color="white" width="200px" height="500px"> <tr> <td style="font-family:Vardana; font-size:30;"> CLEAR THE RACK <td> </tr> <tr> <td style="font-size:20px;"> OCT 2 - OCT 5 </td> </tr> <tr> <td style="font-size:20px;"> Take an <b>extra 25% OFF </b> All Red tag Clearance * </td> </tr> </table></body></html>